# Who is the mysterious person who is apparently acquainted with Eli and enters his house in "Reptile"?

Tags: reptile

In the film *Reptile* (2023), there is a scene where Will Grady (Justin Timberlake) confronts Eli Phillips (Michael Pitt) at Eli's home and demands that Eli return “what [Eli] took from [Will]”. While they are talking, another person (whose face is not revealed) walks into the house. Eli seems to recognize this person and looks nervous. Will asks, “You two know each other, right?" The scene ends with the implication that this person kills Eli off-screen.

**Who is this mysterious person who is apparently acquainted with Eli and enters his house?**

Earlier in the film, Eli had interactions with two other characters: Tom (Benicio del Toro) and Cleary (Ato Essandoh). It can’t be Tom, as the film later reveals, and Cleary doesn’t seem to be involved in any wrongdoing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not specified, tye director was 'having fun'. Probably Wally as he did the other naughty things.

Comment: That movie was an absolute mess.

Answer (score 0):

Cleary was one of the wrongdoers as well. He ”lost” his gun to the suspect — it was a murder attempt to get rid of Tom. Cover up from bad guys, for this was to give Tom a medal for bravery. So it was either him or Wally, and the most logical to the film — it was Cleary, because he visited Eli earlier on, as you pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I tried to keep the athmosphere of the film with the ”…?”.